# Microsoft Exchange 2007 Management Console shows as installed but is not

Tags: windows-7, installation, powershell, exchange, mmc

When I mount the ISO for Exchange 2007 SP1, it shows the steps 1, 2 and 3 greyed out.  They display the following information:

> Step 1:  Install .NET Framework version 2.0 - Installed
>   Step 2:  Install Microsoft Management Console - Installed
>   Step 3:  Install Microsoft Windows Powershell™ - Installed
>   Step 4:  Install Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 SP1

The first three options are greyed out, and obviously I don't want to install the server on my workstation, however I'm unsure how to proceed.  If I download the service from Mircosoft ([link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=11876)), it shows the exact same thing that the ISO setup screen shows.  The program is not listed in Programs and Features or in the "Turn Windows Features on or off".  Why would it be showing as installed if it is not in my programs list?

Is there a directory that I should place or extract these files to, or any other information you guys can give me about the potential cause of this issue.  Is there a registry key that tells Setup that it is installed when it, in fact, is not?  Any information or leads on what to check on would be great.  Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Process monitor would show you what registry keys and files are checked during setup, though thats likely overkill for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In step 2, that is referring to the "Microsoft Management Console" (a.k.a. "MMC") and not the "Microsoft Exchange Management Console" that you are trying to install.  It just means that the MMC is installed on your computer which is standard on Windows these days.

The option you want is indeed "Step 4: Install Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 SP1".  After you choose that option, you can choose the Exchange Server Roles you want to install and one of them should be "Management Tools".  Just uncheck everything else if needed and check the "Management Tools" box and you should be good to go.

Comment: Strangely enough, when I run that, I simply receive an error "Microsoft Exchange Server setup encountered an error".  From the event logs:

     MSExchange Common Event ID 4999.  

Thank you very much for noticing that it just wanted to install MMC and not the Exchange Management Console, now I know that the error is originates elsewhere.  I will do some research and see what I can come up with.  If I find anything I will update here.

If you have any ideas please let me know.  Thank you!

Comment: Ah, that's another strange quirk... For some reason, Windows doesn't detect the Exchange Setup.exe as an installer program so you have to manually run it as Administrator.  I forget to do that all the time when I reinstall it.

Comment: You're awesome.  Thank you :)   This solved my issue.